# Node JS simple function and `this`

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

We know that in a Chrome window, when the following code is executed

```
function test(){
    console.log("function is " + this.test);
}
test();
```

`test` is added as a function to `window` object and it shows

```
function is function test(){
    console.log("function is " + this.test);
}
```

in console.

When I put the same code in a file sample.js, and execute using `node`

```
nodejs$  node sample.js
```

it is giving

```
function is undefined
```

But when I execute the same code directly in `node` terminal

```
nodejs$ node
> function test(){
...         console.log("function is " + this.test);
...     }test();
```

it shows the same output as browser.

Can anybody explain why this happens and how V8 engine executes a Javascript file ? Would like to know more about it, so if possible please provide links to articles and tutorials on this.

Comment: put underscores `is_function_test`

Answer (score 1):

The global object in Node behaves differently. A module has its own scope. You can only create a true global using "global.foo = true"

Answer (score 0):

Good question!

Using the following code in `sample.js`

```
function is function test(){
    console.log("this is " + this);
}
test();
```

Chrome shows that at the time, test() is running in the scope of DOMWindow:

```
this is [object DOMWindow]
```

Node shows that at the time, test() is running in the scope of the object global:

```
this is [object global]
```

But since `test()` has been defined as part of the module sample.js, `this.test` is undefined at the time `test()` is running.

Comment: http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global The reason is not that what you have mentioned

Comment: When test() is running, `this` referrers to the global namespace object. When test() is defined inside a module, it's not part of the global namespace, hence global.test is undefined.


A down vote without a useful explanation is pretty much a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: your comment is more clear than your answer. You yourself answered the downvote reason :) This is fine `test() has been defined as part of the module sample.js` but `this.test is undefined at the time test() is running` is really not.

Answer (score 0):

Basically as @igl mentioned modules have their [own scope](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global)

You can assume that node wraps all your `module` code around a

```
(function () {
// Your module code goes here
})()
```

before executing it. Hence creating a local scope for the module itself.

**Reason:**
It will prevent global scope from getting polluted

**Scenario:** Say you have `module` *sample* which has a *test* function in it and also another module say *sample2* which also has a *test* function in it. If node hadn't created a local scope for your sample and sample2 then either of the *test* function would have overridden the other.

Also you need to understand node is interested only in `module.exports` object of a module

**Example:**

```
var sample = 'you will not see me in global object';
hai = 'but i will be there';
test = function () {
   console.log("function is ",  this.test);
}
console.log(global);
test();
```

Here there is no `var` infront of *hai* and *test* hence it becomes `global` as the same in a browser window scope. Now try executing the above in your local node instance

```
 hai: 'but i will be there',
 test: [Function] }
function is  function () {
    console.log("function is ",  this.test);
}
```

You should see a big list of `global` object's properties and also your test function's definition. *sample* won't be there in the list but